# Ubuntu: safest directory to store backups?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, updates, backup

I am storing backups on a Linux server (Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04).

I do not want these files to be affected by updates, upgrades, etc. Currently I am storing my backups in the `/opt/` directory on the server.

I'm wondering in general, what is the safest location to store files locally on the server? These backups are also pushed to Bitbucket, but I want to make sure my local copy is also in a safe location.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a directory in `/mnt`.

Suppose you have prepared backup scripts that copy your data to `/mnt/backups`, and one day you want to backup to an external drive; then all you need to do is to mount that drive under `/mnt/backups` (add a line to `/etc/fstab`), and all your backup scripts will continue to work.

Other than that, I can't think of any directory being really safer than others as long as you use a dedicated subdirectory for backing up. Well, `/tmp` would not be a good idea. But otherwise, space considerations (if you have spread your OS over more than one partition) or permissions are more important.

Answer (score 0):

There is no directory on your server that is safer then any other and there is no reason updates will affect your backups regardless of location.

The only location for backups I would consider safe would be an external location off site from your server.

With sensitive information I would use encryption, have at least 2 copies in different secure locations, and make sure the backups are working and the server can be restored after a fresh install.

-- Advice --

Personally I use /root for backups on a server. I use 2 directories in /root:

1. /root/etc - I copy any system files I manually edit for /etc into /root/etc as backup. So if I edit /etc/fstab for example, I would copy /etc/fstab to /root/etc/fstab .

I also think you should keep any other system files there that are critical to your server such as fstab, passwd (lists users), apache, php, and any other server config files, etc.

2. I make a /backup directory and here I keep a copy of any files I want backed up such as mysql backups, web pages, scripts I use on the server, firewall rules, and other server data.

As with the first answer, makes external backups simple, just copy /root and if needed /home